# Polish the clay surface using grab without change the original shape on Sculpting

Tags: sculpt

I tried to polish my sphere clay into smooth surface by using grab + shift, but it was ended with small cavity on there. i just want it to be smooth ball surface. Surely this is just for learns, where i want to adapt with some sculpt feature now.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots or a .blend for us to better understand the question? You can edit your question.

Comment: As @Onyx says, a screenshot would help, but have you tried using the Smooth brush?

Comment: Iam sorry for being late to reply your comment, i has been sick for a day before. I Will send it after i get better condition soon as possible